# Autotools issues when linking with OpenMP, MPI and CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda, autotools

I have a project that is compiled with autotools and up until this week needed to be only compiled with OpenMP and MPI support. I have now added a CUDA kernel that I wish to compile into the code under certain circumstances. The compiling of the code goes okay and all of the object files are created. When it comes to linking the objects into the executable the following command is used:

> /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link nvcc  -ccbin=mpicxx -I/usr/local/cuda/include -Xcompiler -std=c++0x -Xcompiler -fopenmp -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcufft   -o utrplauncher utrplauncher-UTRP.o crossovers/libcrossovers.a initialisers/libinitialisers.a mutators/libmutators.a problem/libproblem.a common/libcommon.a variables/libvariables.a ../libraries/framework/libmoeaframework.a ../libraries/ticpp/libticpp.a

Which in turn generates the follwong link command

> libtool: link: nvcc -ccbin=mpicxx -I/usr/local/cuda/include -std=c++0x -fopenmp -o utrplauncher utrplauncher-UTRP.o  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcufft crossovers/libcrossovers.a initialisers/libinitialisers.a mutators/libmutators.a problem/libproblem.a common/libcommon.a variables/libvariables.a ../libraries/framework/libmoeaframework.a ../libraries/ticpp/libticpp.a

This the generates the following error because the -std=c++0x and -fopenmp are interpreted by the CUDA compiler and not the mpicxx compiler.

```
nvcc fatal   : Value 'c++0x' is not defined for option 'std'
```

I can post my configure.ac if that would help but wanted to keep the question concise at the moment.

My question is therefore is it possible to forward the -Xcompiler flags to the mpicxx compiler rather than having them stripped off by libtool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to pass both `-Xcompiler=-std=c++0x` and `-Xcompiler=-fopenmp` directly to the compiler using `-Wc,`, thus `-Xcompiler` is not stripped by `libtool`. For instance following dry-run:

> libtool -n --tag=CXX --mode=link nvcc
>   -ccbin=mpicxx-I/usr/local/cuda/include -Wc,-Xcompiler=-std=c++0x -Wc,-Xcompiler=-fopenmp -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcufft -o utrplauncher utrplauncher-UTRP.o crossovers/libcrossovers.a initialisers/libinitialisers.a mutators/libmutators.a
>   problem/libproblem.a common/libcommon.a variables/libvariables.a
>   ../libraries/framework/libmoeaframework.a
>   ../libraries/ticpp/libticpp.a

generates:

> libtool: link: nvcc -ccbin=mpicxx-I/usr/local/cuda/include
>   -Xcompiler=-std=c++0x -Xcompiler=-fopenmp -o utrplauncher utrplauncher-UTRP.o  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcufft
>   crossovers/libcrossovers.a initialisers/libinitialisers.a
>   mutators/libmutators.a problem/libproblem.a common/libcommon.a
>   variables/libvariables.a ../libraries/framework/libmoeaframework.a
>   ../libraries/ticpp/libticpp.a

Comment: The above works when linking however causes an error when compiling the object files as nvcc does not recognise the -Wc option. Is there a way to set up autotools to compile the code using -Xcompiler and then -Wc,-Xcompiler for the linking?

Comment: @MattJohn: I observed later that you could even omit `-Wc,` and option is still preserved, as it written as `option=value` instead of `option value` (as I checked it's valid for `nvcc`). I don't know if it is documented by `libtool`, so I didn't mention it.